# Null value issue in rendered attribute in outputlink

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:outputLink  rendered="{!IF((list1.size >0 ||list2.size >0) && (ischeck== true ), True, False)}"  >Hello</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Can anyone explain me why I am getting null what is the issue. Link is displaying in the frontend.

Thanks in advance for best answers.

Comment: add null checks for list1 & list2 and use size() instead of just size

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Are you sure about using parenthesis on `size()`? It works fine without them, and adding them just seems to give an error: "Error: Unknown function list1.size. Check spelling."

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see here is that you don't have a `value` property set on the outputlink. It should work for you if you add:

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://www.sample.com" ...
```

Comment: value="#01" is added..i forgt to mention it here

Comment: ya its throwing error if I replace size to size() @ martin

Comment: @Gayathri Is the id on the tag you are navigating to an `<apex:` tag? If so, the problem is likely that the id in the browser is different than in the Visualforce markup. You could try generating the id in the link with the [$Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_access.htm) global variable. i.e. `value="#{!$Component.theId}"`

Comment: Hi martin...value="#01" means I have different pageblock so if I click on it Its going to that pageblock. my issue resolved...I did bulk upload so its working

Comment: @Gayathri good to hear.